# Store the row number in a VBS script as variable and refer to it

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am writing a script from VBA and using a recorded action in SAP GUI screen. I want the script to enter a certain transaction paste a certain value (contract number) and then go to a certain row in a table double click it and do a certain action inside.

I use a while loop in VBA and in an Excel sheet I store the contract number, the number of the row on which the script should double click and then paste the value I need once it enters. It should do it until cells in column a are empty.

You can see in the VBS part of the code below that I tried to replace the row number with the variable "row", but the code does not accept that.

If I leave a number there it actually does what I want as long as the number is the correct one for what I try to do.

Can someone help me with this one? I go around this with if statements should the number of possibilities for the row number is limited, but that could mean to have a very long code, and potentially something can be missed.

Is it possible to make the row number refer to a variable in the code.

I already tried to declare the variable in VBS but it does not work as well.

Code:

```
'We declared the parameter for the while function in excel

Dim cont As String
Dim row As Integer
Dim rep As String

Dim j As Integer
j = 2

With ThisWorkbook
While Cells(j, 1) <> ""
cont = Cells(j, 1).Value
row = Cells(j, 3).Value
rep = Cells(j, 4).Value

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
  Set SAPApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
  Set SAPCon = SAPApp.Children(0)
  Set Session = SAPCon.Children(0)

  If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject Session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
End If

Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").Text = cont
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBAK-VBELN").caretPosition = 8
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4426/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4908/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_KONTRAKT/ctxtVBAP-KDMAT[5,row]").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4426/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4908/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_KONTRAKT/ctxtVBAP-KDMAT[5,row]").caretPosition = 6
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\10").Select
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\10/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4454/ctxtVBAP-KDMAT").Text = rep
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\10/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4454/ctxtVBAP-KDMAT").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_ITEM/tabpT\10/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4454/ctxtVBAP-KDMAT").caretPosition = 3
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

j = j + 1
Wend

End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use the variable row as a variable instead you use the string "row". Have a look at rule [#5 here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/5-rules-for-embedding-strings-in-vba-code/) . "row" does not mean anything to the SAPGUI.

Try this

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4426/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4908/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_KONTRAKT/ctxtVBAP-KDMAT[5," & CStr(Row) & "]").SetFocus
```

You need to do this for the second string as well.

You also use the wrong key word. This is not SAP ABAP, this is [SAPGUI scripting](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-8971).

Comment: Thanks very much Storax! This worked perfectly! I will definitely read more about this topic.